# Swift protocol with associatedtype (ambiguous for type lookup)

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols, associated-types

I need to create generic function in protocol with default implementation in extension. It func should work with item as `enum`:`RawRepresentable` where `RawValue == String` always. I tried

```
protocol RequiresEnum: class {
    associatedtype SectionIdentifierEnum: RawRepresentable // how this add restriction to RawValue == String

    func test<T: SectionIdentifierEnum>(identifier: T) where T.RawValue == String
}

enum RequiresEnumDefault: String {
    case `default`
}

extension RequiresEnum where Self: UIViewController, SectionIdentifierEnum.RawValue == String {

    typealias SectionIdentifierEnum = RequiresEnumDefault

    func test<T: SectionIdentifierEnum>(identifier: T) where T.RawValue == String {
        print(T.rawValue)
    }

}
```

but i have errors

> - 'SectionIdentifierEnum' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
> - 'RawValue' is not a member type of 'T'

Any solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally when covering generics in the context of protocols, the generic typeholder is seen as representable by an `associatedtype` of the protocol. In your example this would be `SectionIdentifierEnum`, which acts as a placeholder for a constrained *type*. `SectionIdenfierEnum` is not, however, a protocol by itself, so cannot use it as a type constraint in a generic method. You *can*, however, use it as the type itself in your `test(...)` method.

---

#### Swift 3.1

Now, currently (Swift 3.1), you can't add sophisticated type constrains to an `associatedtype`. You could can, however, supply a default implementation available only for the case the where `Self` derives from `UIViewController` and implements the `RequiresEnum` protocol by setting the `SectionIdentifierEnum` type to the concrete `RequiresEnumDefault` type. The latter will ascertain that the associated `RawValue` is `String` for this default implementation, as the `RawValue` of the concrete `RequiresEnumDefault` type is `String`.

E.g.:

```
// Swift 3.1
// ---------
// Types that implement this protocol mustn't necessarily use a
// `SectionIdentifierEnum` type where `SectionIdentifierEnum.RawValue` 
// is constrained to equal `String`. 
protocol RequiresEnum: class {
    associatedtype SectionIdentifierEnum: RawRepresentable

    func test(identifier: SectionIdentifierEnum)
}

enum RequiresEnumDefault: String {
    case `default`
}

// This extension, however, is only available for types that use
// `RequiresEnumDefault ` as the concrete type of `SectionIdentifierEnum`
// (in which case `SectionIdentifierEnum.RawValue` is `String`).
extension RequiresEnum where Self: UIViewController, SectionIdentifierEnum == RequiresEnumDefault {

    func test(identifier: SectionIdentifierEnum) {
        print(identifier.rawValue)
    }
}

// Example usage.
class MyViewController : UIViewController, RequiresEnum {
    typealias SectionIdentifierEnum = RequiresEnumDefault
    // ...
}

let foo = MyViewController()
foo.test(identifier: RequiresEnumDefault.default) 
  // prints "default" (using extension:s default implementation)
```

Above, the default implementation of `test(...)` is only available when `SectionIdentifierEnum` equals the concrete type `RequireEnumDefault` (and `Self` derives from `UIViewController` ...). If instead you want it to only be available when `SectionIdentifierEnum` is *any enum with `String` typed `RawValue`*, you modify the type constraint of the extensions accordingly:

```
protocol RequiresEnum: class {
    associatedtype SectionIdentifierEnum: RawRepresentable

    func test(identifier: SectionIdentifierEnum)
}

enum RequiresEnumDefault: String {
    case `default`
}

extension RequiresEnum where Self: UIViewController, SectionIdentifierEnum.RawValue == String {

    func test(identifier: SectionIdentifierEnum) {
        print(identifier.rawValue)
    }
}


// Example usage.
enum EnumWithStringRawValue: String {
    case foo
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController, RequiresEnum {
    typealias SectionIdentifierEnum = EnumWithStringRawValue
    // ...
}

let foo = MyViewController()
foo.test(identifier: EnumWithStringRawValue.foo)
    // prints "foo" (using extension:s default implementation)
```

---

Once Swift 4 is released, you'll be able to add more sophisticated constraints to `associatedtype`:s, as per the implementation of Swift evolution proposal:

- [SE-0142: Permit where clauses to constrain associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md)

In which case the above can be modified into:

```
// Swift 4
// -------
// Here, all types that implement this protocol must use a
// `SectionIdentifierEnum` type where `SectionIdentifierEnum.RawValue` 
// is equal to `String`. 
protocol RequiresEnum: class {
    associatedtype SectionIdentifierEnum: RawRepresentable 
        where SectionIdentifierEnum.RawValue == String

    func test(identifier: SectionIdentifierEnum)
}

enum RequiresEnumDefault: String {
    case `default`
}

// For the specific case where `SectionIdentifierEnum` equals
// `RequiresEnumDefault` (and where `Self` derives from `UIViewController`), 
// this default implementation is readily available.
extension RequiresEnum where Self: UIViewController, SectionIdentifierEnum == RequiresEnumDefault {

    func test(identifier: SectionIdentifierEnum) {
        print(identifier.rawValue)
    }

}

// Example usage.
class MyViewController : UIViewController, RequiresEnum {
    typealias SectionIdentifierEnum = RequiresEnumDefault
    // ...
}

let foo = MyViewController()
foo.test(identifier: RequiresEnumDefault.default) 
  // prints "default" (using extension:s default implementation)
```

Likewise modifying the constraint on the default implementation of `test(...)` not only to the case where `SectionIdentifierEnum` equals `RequiresEnumDefault` (but to any enum: in this case we know such enum will always have a `RawValue` `String`, due to the constraint on the `associatedtype` in the protocol definition).

```
protocol RequiresEnum: class {
    associatedtype SectionIdentifierEnum: RawRepresentable 
        where SectionIdentifierEnum.RawValue == String

    func test(identifier: SectionIdentifierEnum)
}

enum RequiresEnumDefault: String {
    case `default`
}

// From the constraint on the `RawValue` of `SectionIdentifierEnum`
// above, we know that `RawValue` equals `String`.
extension RequiresEnum where Self: UIViewController {

    func test(identifier: SectionIdentifierEnum) {
        print(identifier.rawValue)
    }
}

// Example usage.
enum EnumWithStringRawValue: String {
    case foo
}
class MyViewController : UIViewController, RequiresEnum {
    typealias SectionIdentifierEnum = EnumWithStringRawValue
    // ...
}

let foo = MyViewController()
foo.test(identifier: EnumWithStringRawValue.foo) 
  // prints "foo" (using extension:s default implementation)
```